# How to hide/remove Cordova Windows 10 app back button?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, windows-10, windows-10-universal

The windows 10 app generated by cordova shows a back button on extreme top left, when I run the app in desktop. When user taps the button, the application behaves like a web. This option is really annoying.

**Is there anyway that I can hide or remove the back button?** Looking for solution preferably in Javascript, C# can be optional.

Comment: if you found nothing in the docs about a function that does this, you still can add a little extra CSS to hide it. A cordova app being a html page, a simple `display: none;` should work. (Trick: with ionic while running app in a browser, you could open web developper tools by doing a double right click, don't know if still possible, to explore the html and get the id or class of the element to hide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway that I can hide or remove the back button? Looking for solution preferably in Javascript, C# can be optional.

If you are refering to the back button on Title bar, you can use the following codes in cordova to disable the back button:

```
if (cordova.platformId = "windows")
{
    var currentView = Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.getForCurrentView();
    currentView.appViewBackButtonVisibility = Windows.UI.Core.AppViewBackButtonVisibility.collapsed;
}
```

Comment: Where should I write this. I mean filename in cordova app? Please suggest or provide some code snippet. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Tanu You can add the codes anywhere after the app has been initialized. (ex: `onDeviceReady` in index.js)

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyK I tried it and Visual Studio 2017 doesn't recognize cordova or Windows variable. What can I do?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT please help me, I try the above code in my ionic3 app but I get an error on "Windows.UI.Core" that Cannot find name 'Windows' please help me how can you use the above code in my app.

Comment: @Neotrix I'm not quite familiar with Ionic 3 together with typescript, but since it's built on cordova, it should work. I suggest you try it on an blank ionic app. Notes, there probably no intellisense support for `Windows.XX` namespace

Comment: @Neotrixs Try it with declare var <variableName> :any; See https://gist.github.com/hamburml/0d1c5ac81435e2e099be3eb24b2567d8