# How to hide/remove Ionic 4 Cordova Windows 10 app back button?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, uwp

I previously use to use the following to remove the Windows back arrow (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054317/how-to-hide-remove-cordova-windows-10-app-back-button)):

```
    private hideWindowsTitleBackArrow(): void {
        try {
          let w: any = window;
          if (w.cordova != undefined && w.cordova.platformId == "windows") {
            let currentView = w.Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.getForCurrentView();
            currentView.appViewBackButtonVisibility = w.Windows.UI.Core.AppViewBackButtonVisibility.collapsed;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          this.logger.error(`Error in hideWindowsTitleBackArrow: ${error}`);
        }
      }
```

When I run this now after my Ionic 4 update,  now get the following warning..

```
The method Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsPane.getForCurrentView has been deprecated. SettingsPane is deprecated and might not work on all platforms. For more info, see MSDN.
```

And it no longer works...

[image]

Is there perhaps an updated way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the code above still works, however, I now need to call it a bit later.

Previously I would call straight after `platform.ready()`

ie

```
 private async initializeApp() : Promise<void> {
   try {              
    await this.platform.ready();                      
    this.statusBar.styleDefault();      
    this.hideWindowsTitleBackArrow();
```

To get it to work I now put the call in a timer...

```
setTimeout(() => this.hideWindowsTitleBackArrow(), 100);
```

Comment: I am very glad that you have found a solution. You can mark your reply as an answer. This will help more people, thank you.